# Update in stored procedure with filter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I create table

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
ID int,
FirstName nvarchar(50),
LastName nvarchar(50)
)
```

Have stored procedure where

```
UPDATE tbl
SET FistName = @firstName  , LastName = @lastName
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Now when I call my stored procedure  `exec myProc 1,'John',''` want update
only those columns which I write. For example if I have in my table values  :

```
ID : 1
FirstName: Bob
LastName : Brown
```

after exec it must be

```
ID : 1
FirstName: John
LastName : Brown
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET FirstName = 
case 
    when @firstName is null or @firstName = '' then firstName 
    else @firstName
end,
LastName = 
case 
    when @lastName is null or @lastName = '' then lastName 
    else @lastName
end
WHERE ID = @ID
```

Generally is correct manage the NULL and the empty string value

Comment: thank you for help , but if I want update many values is any way do it without case ?

Comment: the case statement manages the input value, not number of rows. Numer of rows has managed by @id in yuor where condition ;)